# Foriegn key shown as a drop down. Any way to show it as a text value ? (django)

Tags: python, django

In my application, on page1, I create a Project object and then on page 2, I create a batch object.
The "batch" object has a many-to-one relationship with "Project".
It therefore needs to display the Project object when batch form is called.

I can show the Project object on a batch form but it is shown as a drop down.
I would like it to be shown as a field value but it doesnt work.
Can you please help.
Thanks.

models.py

```
Class Project
name = models.CharField()

Class Batch
name = models.CharField()
project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

template.py

```
<a href="{% url 'create_batch_url' pk=project.id %}" role="button" >Link to Batch</a>
```

passing the foreign key from 
urls.py

```
path('batch/new/<int:pk>', batch_views.review_batch, name='create_batch_url'),
```

views.py

```
simple view which calls the model form
```

forms.py

```
class BatchForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = ('name', 'project',)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        project_id = kwargs.pop("project_id")

        #Only show the project where the request came from
        self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(id=project_id)
```

Comment: What if you'll add `project= forms.CharField()` to model form?

Comment: tried that. The form shows an empty charField. I cant figure out how to populate the project object to this charField()

Comment: Try `project = forms.ModelChoiceField()`  [More Info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

Comment: tried this: project = ModelChoiceField(Project.objects.filter(id=project_id))
but still shows drop down instead of a text field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `widgets` variable to the form meta. [Link to the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets)

```py
from django.forms import TextInput

class BatchForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = ('name', 'project',)
        widgets = {'project': TextInput}

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        project_id = kwargs.pop("project_id")

        #Only show the project where the request came from
        self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(id=project_id)
```

Comment: This does show project as a text field tag but the field is empty.
(The project object is empty)
my template is just a table with a {{ form }} in it.

Comment: @Umair you'll have to provide initial data in the view. The original post doesn't provide view code so I can't provide specifics, but a line like `form = BatchForm(initial={'project': project_id})` should do. [More info in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)